# Imageloader always display the wrong picture

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm developing a android app. And I used the `ImageLoader` to load the picture from service.The code is as below:

```
    public ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(.this));
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error).cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisc(true).displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(5)).build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(my_pic, holder.head, options);
```

I used this code in a `getView()` in a activity. And I could read the pic from service, but the holder.head always display the picture `R.drawable.ic_stub`.
Before this code , I also used `ImageLoader` to display the pic in function `onCreate()`, and it worker well, they are in the same file.

Why can't I display the correct pic?

Comment: You seem to have a logic issue in setting the image to load.

Answer (score 0):

use image loader like this .....
First initialize

```
 DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config;

              // OnCreate{
                defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                        .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).
                                showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.noimage).
                                showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.noimage)
                        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

                config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext())
                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                        .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

                ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}
```

public class SubCatAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
.....
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public SubCatAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<SubCategoriesVO> itmes) {
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    ....
    imageLoader = imageLoader.getInstance();
}

....
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.subcat_list_item, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dd_icon);
        .....

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    SubCategoriesVO item = searched_itmes.get(position);

    if (imageLoader != null)
        imageLoader.displayImage(item.getImg(), holder.imgIcon);
   ....
    return convertView;
}}
```

add permission to access internet

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: You should remove your personal codes from your answer !

Comment: In your code, you didn't use the option in imageLoader.displayImage(item.getImg(), holder.imgIcon);

Comment: you have to initialize it once on app launch.

Comment: @SohailZahid  I have initialized, but it still didn't work. Thanks for your answer all the same.

Comment: @EricCheng have you added internet Permission in menifest.